# Mulitple column name in spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data

**Model**

```
@Column(name="Desc", name="des", name="DS")
private String description;
```

How can I mention multiple name of column ? so, that if any one found it map value to description?

Comment: `@Column` is the name of the actual database column - a database column can't have multiple names - or am I not getting something

Comment: yes , @Column is the name of the actual database column, but sometime we use alias. like select description as DS from table.

Comment: the alias works on query level only. could you please describe your actual problem, i.e. where you're stuck? because the question as it's asked now can only have one answer: "a column can only have one name" (there's `AttributeOverride` for using the same e.g. `Embeddable` in multiple tables though, but that's clearly not the question)

Comment: @msparer I have many stored procedures, some returns Description `Desc`, some returning `des`  and some returning `DS`, currently I have `@Column(name="Desc")`, SPs that returning `des` or `DS`, in result description is null

Comment: seems like you're mixing up aliases with column names. surely your stored procedures only use **one** column name

Comment: the way you put it, it's a client requirement that one database column can have multiple names. that's one weird client requirement since it's impossible.

Comment: @msparer Actually Problem is that , when we put join with two table , some table have same name , so, for this we need to use alias for one column.

Comment: yes, but `@Column(name)` is the **actual name of the column** NOT the name of the alias

Answer (score 0):

> How can I mention multiple name of column ?

You can't. A database does not allow columns to have multiple names, hence you can't map multiple column names to a class field.

> so, that if any one found it map value to description?

If you have multiple stored procedures that return in their respective result set **"Desc"**, **"des"**, **"ds"** and you need to map this to the same Java class - you need to define different row mappers and describe the mapping there.

For example let's say you have SP1 and SP2 and you want both result sets from those to be mapped to ResultDto.
ResultDto looks like:

```
public class ResultDto {
  private String name; //always maps to DB column "name"
  private String desc; //maps to different DB columns - "ds", "desc"
  //ommitted..
}
```

You can define a base row mapper and define the mapping for all overlapping fields of all Stored Procs result sets.

Code Example:

```
protected static abstract class BaseRowMapper implements RowMapper<ResultDto> {
   public abstract ResultDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException;

   protected void mapBase(ResultSet rs, ResultDto resultDto) throws SQLException {
      resultDto.setName(rs.getString("name")); //map all overlapping fields/columns here
   }
}

private static class SP1RowMapper extends BaseRowMapper {

  @Override
 public ResultDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
   ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
   mapBase(rs, resultDto);
   resultDto.setDescription(rs.getString("ds"));
   return resultDto;
 }
}

private static class SP2RowMapper extends BaseRowMapper {

 @Override
 public ResultDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
   ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
   mapBase(rs, resultDto);
   resultDto.setDescription(rs.getString("desc"));
   return resultDto;
 }
}
```

I don't know how you call the Stored Procedures, but if you use Spring's `SimpleJdbcCall`, the code will look like:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(datasource)
  .withProcedureName("SP NAME")
  .declareParameters(
     //Stored Proc params
   )
  .returningResultSet("result set id", rowMapperInstance);
```